# NSPredicateEditor callBack when NSPredicate added or changed

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

I am on XCode 9.3, objective-c, OSX not iOS.

I use an NSPredicateEditor in my app which works fine so far. However i have a view that shall update its content with the predicates set in the editor (basically the view shows filtered arrays).

Currently i have a "Refresh" button the user needs to hit to update the view once he changes something in the editor.

I was wondering if there's a way to trigger my method to update the view automatically when a predicateRow is **added** OR **changed**?

I tried to add an observer to the NSPredicateEditor.objectValue - but i don't receive a notification.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [self.predicateEditor.objectValue addObserver:self selector:@selector(predicateChangedByUser:) name:@"Test" object:nil];
}

- (void)predicateChangedByUser:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"Changed: %@",aNotification);
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't receive a notification because you're trying to combine a notification and KVO. Some solutions:

Solution A: connect the action of the predicate editor to an action method.

Solution B: observe notification `NSRuleEditorRowsDidChangeNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(predicateChangedByUser:) name:NSRuleEditorRowsDidChangeNotification object:self.predicateEditor];

- (void)predicateChangedByUser:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"predicateChangedByUser");
}
```

Solution C: observe keypath `predicate` of the predicate editor. `predicate` is a property of `NSRuleEditor`.

```
static void *observingContext = &observingContext;

[self.predicateEditor addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"predicate" options:0 context:&observingContext];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == &observingContext)
        NSLog(@"observeValueForKeyPath %@", keyPath);
    else
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```

Solution D: bind the value of the editor to a predicate property.

Comment: Thank you! You're always a great help! One question - the delegate protocol requires several methods. Each of them returnes a value. I did not find any example on how to setup them correctly. Any hint?

Comment: The documentation of `NSPredicateEditor` says "Unlike NSRuleEditor, NSPredicateEditor does not depend on its delegate to populate its rows (and does not call the populating delegate methods).". `NSPredicateEditor` uses its row templates. You don't have to implement the data providing methods.

Comment: I've already read that. But -> once i conform to NSRuleEditorDelegate protocol the compiler wants the required methods. All methods have return values. The question was on: How to setup these methods correctly - i did not ind any example..

Comment: The methods are not called so it doesn't matter what the return value is. You can return `0` and `nil`. In my test app, the delegate doesn't conform to the `NSRuleEditorDelegate` protocol and I didn't notice the required methods. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 'NSPredicateEditor' has an 'action' selector that can be connected in code or by using an outlet in the interface designer to a function, like this:

```
- (IBAction)predicateChanged:(id)sender {
    // Update your view
}
```